# Bazel select build file depending on toolchain

Tags: build, bazel

I want to change build file of a http_archive depending on the toolchain. The idea is to use a different library for a different architecture. But I could not figure out how. In my  .bzl file I defined

```
load(
"@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:utils.bzl",
"maybe",)
load(
"@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl",
"http_archive",
)

def silkit():
    maybe(
        http_archive,
        name = "silkit",
        build_file = <select-build-file>,
        url = "silkit-url-in artifactory",
    )
```

I defined silkit_aarch64.BUILD and silkit_x86_64.BUILD under the same folder. In my .bazelrc file, I defined

```
build:aarch64 --platforms=//toolchain/gcc_12.3.0_aarch64:aarch64
```

I need to get this info in .bzl file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this with [select](https://bazel.build/docs/configurable-attributes#select-and-dependencies) in a single BUILD file. I can't think of anything which actually requires separate repositories. For example, if you currently have this:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "silkit",
    hdrs = glob(["usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/*.h"]),
    includes = ["usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu"],
    srcs = glob(["usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libnsilkit.so.0.*"]),
)
```

and this:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "silkit",
    hdrs = glob(["usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/*.h"]),
    includes = ["usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"],
    srcs = glob(["usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsilkit.so.0.*"]),
)
```

then you can combine them like this:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "silkit",
    hdrs = select({
        "@platforms//cpu:aarch64": glob(["usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/*.h"]),
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64": glob(["usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/*.h"]),
    }),
    includes = select({
        "@platforms//cpu:aarch64": ["usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu"],
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64": ["usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"],
    }),
    srcs = select({
        "@platforms//cpu:aarch64": glob(["usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libnsilkit.so.0.*"]),
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64": glob(["usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsilkit.so.0.*"]),
    }),
)
```

That's the approach I've taken when there's a single archive file for both platforms.

If you really need separate repositories (if there are different archive files for each for example), then you need to create separate repositories and then use select to choose which one to use. Bazel won't download the deselected one for `bazel build` commands. Something like this:

```py
def silkit():
    maybe(
        http_archive,
        name = "silkit_aarch64",
        build_file = "silkit_aarch64.BUILD",
        url = "silkit-aarch64-url-in artifactory",
    )
    maybe(
        http_archive,
        name = "silkit_x86_64",
        build_file = "silkit_x86_64.BUILD",
        url = "silkit-x86_64-url-in artifactory",
    )
```

and then put something like this to select the appropriate one to use:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "silkit",
    deps = select({
        "@platforms//cpu:aarch64": ["@silkit_aarch64//:silkit"],
        "@platforms//cpu:x86_64": ["@silkit_x86_64//:silkit"],
    }),
)
```

I've found `cc_library` works better for this than [alias](https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#alias) due to some complications with forwarding providers, but for simple cases like this either will work.

Comment: Ohh it helped me so much. Thank you a lot!!!